# Capture innerHTML using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I am using JavaScript to assign a value to an empty div through document.getElementById('').innerHTML which works fine and I can see the words update and come up on the browser. I then try to capture those words but keep getting it as undefined.

My HTML is

```
<div id="name"> </div>
```

JavaScript executes this:

```
function doneloading(first_name) {
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = first_name;
}
```

I try to capture that using:

```
var photoname = document.getElementById('name').value;
alert(photoname);
```

Is it not possible to capture innerHTML in general?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When are you calling that capturing code?

Comment: @Ahmad You are setting the `innerHTML` property, but retrieving the `value` property. You should try to retrieve the `innerHTML` property.

Comment: I am definitely calling it after the div has updated and shows the name on the browser

Comment: @kalaero Thanks for your comment. I tried that before posting my question and it didn't work either. Still came as undefined...

Comment: @kalaero I just tried it again and it worked this time. Wow. Thanks alot! Wouldn't have tried it again without your help :)

Comment: @Ahmad You're welcome! I rang up your code and told it to behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var photoname = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML;
```

Comment: I tried that before and it still came up as undefined but its working now for some reason so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can access the value within the element the same way you set it.

```
var innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML;
```

This will also return any embedded HTML tags' code in the particular element. See w3school's documentation for the [innerHTML property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp).

Comment: I tried that before and it still came up as undefined but its working now for some reason so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML output code is html code:
Such as:

```
<div id="demo"><div id="name">The demo said is right</div></div>
var domNameHtml=document.getElementById('name').innerHTML;
```

the domNameHtml value is The demo said is right
If you want change the dom object about div html code;
Must be like this:

```
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML='<div id="name">The demo said is right</div><h1>Integral is my</h1>';
```

the html code Change :

```
<div id="demo"><div id="name">The demo said is right</div><h1>Integral is my</h1></div>
```

If you want change the dom object about div text code;

var text=document.getElementById('name').innerTest;
the text value is [The demo said is right] Removed html code

Want to be able to help you